# Capture click event of the dynamically generated tabpanels

Tags: asp.net, tabpanel

I have created tab panel dynamically and trying to display them now by using following code:

```
   AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tab = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
   tab.HeaderText = dirList[i];
   tab.ID = "ID" + i+1;
   TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tab);
     if(tab.selectedevent =="dirList[i]")
     {
     }
```

Here, I want to capture dynamic click event of the tabpanels. can you please help with that..
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the event handler for the dynamically created tab. The below is for a button, but it should be the same for a tabpanel.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

protected void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    // identify which button was clicked and perform necessary actions
}
```

Comment: Yup youyong it would be same... I tried it with tab panel but I am messed up with the things..